# Codificación en Python 2.7

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7, utf-8, codificación

Mysql me esta devolviendo registros, los cuales tienen acentos. Su codificación es ut8, pero en Python los acentos me los muestra como /xfa, ¿cómo puedo convertir esto?

```
nombres = [x[0] for x in run_query("SELECT nombre FROM equipos WHERE estado = 1")]

print nombres
```

Y por consola:

```
python script.py
```

Comment: ¿Estás mostrando el resultado desde un intérprete interactivo, o es desde un script en ejecución y usando `print`? Tiene pinta de que lo que estás viendo es la representación de la cadena, en lugar de su versión imprimible.

Comment: Lo realizo con un print, me falta algo?

Comment: En principio no. Pon por favor un trozo de código donde muestres cómo lo imprimes y el resultado que ves.

Comment: nombres = [x[0] for x in run_query("SELECT nombre FROM equipos WHERE estado = 1")]

print nombres

Comment: Ajá, lo que me temía. Lo que imprimes (`nombres`) no es una cadena, sino una lista. Por tanto python te muestra la representación de esa lista, con sus corchetes y comillas alrededor de cada elemento, y la representación interna (unicode) de cada cadena. El contenido de la cadena está bien, no necesitas recodificarlo, pero tienes que imprimir cada cadena individual y no la lista. Por ejemplo: `for e in nombres: print e`

Comment: Es posible que al imprimir la cadena individual falle, si no conoce el encoding de la terminal, pues intentará codificarlo entonces como ASCII y con los acentos no podrá. En ese caso, debes hacer la codificación a tu terminal explícita. Por ejemplo, si tu terminal es utf8, `for e in nombres: print e.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: Que tal, y que propones?